# TeXStudio cannot find packages

Tags: texstudio

I use TeXStudio 2.9.4 and TeXLive 2015. They are not installed from the same bundle.

TeXStudio cannot find any package at all. How do I let it look for packages at the right place?

Comment: Would you have installed TeX Studio before TeX Live?

Comment: Did you read [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253530/latex-cannot-find-installed-packages.

Comment: @cfr, yes I installed everything, the problem is that it cannot find the packages, not that the packages are not installled.

Comment: @Bernard, I installed `TeXlive` vannilla first, then `TeXStudio`. It should be noted that `LyX` finds everything perfectly because we can specify the path in the Settings. There is no such setting in TeXLive.

Comment: How exactly did you add texlive to the path? It is a common mistake to add it to `.bashrc`. Add it to `.profile` instead. Log out and in again. Then TS works just fine

Comment: I add to both of them, since adding to only one of them did not work! Here is how `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive:2015/bin/i386-linux:$PATH` and the same for `MANPATH` and `INFOPATH` with `export MANPATH` and `export INFOPATH` respectively.

Comment: Did you follow the linked instructions? How did you install TeXStudio? If you did not install the dummy package and you used your distro's package manager, you will have reinstalled a second version of TeX Live. Also, you want e.g. `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/i386-linux:$PATH`.

Comment: I followed, and I redid all the installations. Now it partly works, but not satisfactorily. Thank you very much for all your instructions!